# javascript to check "success" response after click the SEND button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get response for input of a webpage  http://connect.inmarsat.com/Services/Land/IsatPhone/SMS/sms.html

- I complete the number with 1234567 and use test @ test .com and some text
- After I clicked SEND, I like to check, if it was successful
  by checking, if "Thank you!" is shown...but in the html is no change
  so I like to check the "code", but I have no knowledge about,
  or if this is possible

before input and click the SEND button:

```
<div id="isatPhone_messageBox">
  <div>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="title"></span>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

after click the SEND button:

```
<div id="isatPhone_messageBox" style="display: block;">
  <div class="">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="title">Thank you!</span>
    <span class="text">Your message has been successfully sent.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For sure this line is wrong, get back "null" always :

```
javascript:(function() {element.getElementsByClassName('title');})()
```

use in AI2 block WebVieWTools [image]

Comment: Using `+87077 1234567` or `1234567` says it's an invalid Inmarsat number format.

Comment: Thank you for trying , it is +870771234567 ...

Comment: ... and after clicking SEND button, the code change, like shown.   This i like to read out, some how.

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be it sorted out your problem. your point is not clear but due to reps, i have comment here.

```
javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByClassName('title');})()
```

Comment: That does nothing. But neither did the original. Something like `console.log(document.querySelector(".title"),innerHTML)` would

Comment: Based on the code you've shared, the original code we don't know where `element` is declared. Using `document` will ensure that the whole page is checked for the elements with the `title` class.

Comment: @mplungjan since its a javascript document.querySelector will not work. its a part of angularJS. from best of my knowledge

Comment: @TaylorRahul then you need to update your knowledge :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: It is better supported than `document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: @mplungjan sorry mate

Comment: What do you mean "better supported"? Please compare 
https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector and https://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Comment: And I apologise for the comma - it should of course be `console.log(document.querySelector(".title").innerHTML)`

Comment: @Sean getElementsByClassName is not supported by IE8, but querySelector is

Comment: Are you actually supporting IE8? :O

Comment: Until far too recently, yes. But in any case querySelector(".className") is much nicer than getElementsByClassName("className")[0] - and why not be as compatible as possible

Comment: hy, i am just reading the code of the webpage above, i can't change anything.  the code change after pushing the SEND button.  but i can't jet check, if "Thank you!" is shown ...

Answer (score 0):

As written, this function does not return a value:

> ```
> javascript:(function() {element.getElementsByClassName('title');})()
> ```

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079563/3161253), the `element` does not appear to be defined. You'll have more luck searching the `document`.

```
javascript:(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('title'); })()
```

This will return a HTMLCollection. I expect you'll still have problems though. The form is likely sending an AJAX request, waiting for the response, then updating the text. I'm not familiar with WebViewTools but it doesn't look like you're doing waiting for the request to return.

Comment: Thank you,i tried your 
javascript:(function() { return  document.getElementsByClassName('title'); })()
and it give back "{}" on all other pages ,
on the responce page it give back "null"

Comment: i have add 1 second waiting before checking with sending the javascript, 
still "null" responce, but it react for the class "title" , thats ok.

Comment: how i can get the value of the class "title"   
i wait now 3 seconds before sending the javascript,   
both , before and after have "title"  , but after the value is "Thank you!"  , time is not the reason

Comment: actual i check / send the javascript before click the SEND button and after it,    both give back a "null"  ,   the change of the value is not seen,

Comment: Many Thanks for your help,  
i took your advice and combined it with a other from a other forum AI2.   
Now i use 
javascript:(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].textContent; })()   
and it works perfectly,     THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

Hello every body and many Thanks to all of you.

You helped me out of the "sh...t"

your tips and ideas bring me with help of other forums to this solution :

```
javascript:(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].textContent; })()
```

THANK YOU !!!

Comment: Be careful, if there's ever another element with the "title" class you're probably going to want to get **all** the text. If you're trying to support older browers, try something like:

    var result = '';
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
      result += element.textContent; // or .innerText
    }
    return result;

Comment: ok, thanks, i will, in the moment i check the page with only one "title".

Comment: Hello Sean,  how would look a javascript line for all this ?   I can only send one line and what i get back, i have to life with ...

Comment: Hy all,   right now, i only get "" back, exept from null all the time the 'title' is empty ... the "" is when the responce is shown, "Thank you!" i cant get anymore ...

Comment: it was me, the bug in front of the device ... me. OK again